# Editing state field of woocommerce check out page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was editing my woocommerce checkout page(plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php ) so as to edit the state which was shown 
in it

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );


function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);

     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Kindly, but you are trying to override WC core files (plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php) and this is not recommended because you will lose all changes when plugin get updated. You are on the wrong location: You have to copy woocommerce "templates" folder to your active child theme or theme and rename it "woocommerce". **(See this: [Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/))**. To customize woocommerce you can override the templates (as explained) and/or use **hooks (action and filters)** as in your question link tutorial.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, because you don't tell what you are really trying to do editing **checkout page**. The **right templats files** are located in your newly added "woocommerce" folder (inside your active theme, as explained before) **on "checkout" subfolder**. An advice: To better get helped, please include the code you are using, updating your question, telling us what is working and what not . Thanks. I hope this will help you.